# Can Matplotlib return a bar's label using a mouse click event?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to have a barchart return a bar's label when clicked, but I can't find an example where this particular task has been done on a bar chart. I found this sample barchart from Matplotlib, but it doesn't have any events set up:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x, labels)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to [add event handling to the Figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/users/event_handling.html). You can do that with

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

This tells matplotlib to run the function `onclick` whenever you click on your figure. `onclick` should have the signature

```
def onclick(event):
```

and you can access for example the x-coordinate of the mouse press using `event.xdata`. In your case, if you are always plotting the bars at each integer position on the x-axis, you can transform the x-coordinate of the press to the nearest integer and access that element of your labels. You can obtain the index for that element as

```
idx = int(event.xdata.round())
```

Finally, `event.inaxes` gets you the Axis-instance that you have clicked in, so you can access the axis labels with `lbls = event.inaxes.get_xticklabels()`. Then you can write `onclick` as

```
def onclick(event):
    ax = event.inaxes
    x = event.xdata
    lbls = ax.get_xticklabels()
    idx = int(x.round())
    lbl = lbls[idx]
    print(lbl.get_text())
```

to have the label of the *nearest* bar printed. This code will, however, still print something if you click between the bars. If you want to make sure that you are clicking a bar, you can get the rectangles used to plot the bar chart with `ax.patches` and check first whether the click was actually within one of the rectangles.